# QuerySelectorAll div and change its width onmouseover Javascript

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, queryselector

I'm new to this and I'm trying to select multiple **.card** in my html (the share with gray background color)

[image: Card]

and change its width onmouseover, I also have contents that are in `display:none` and make all appear onmouseover using javascript, this is the code I have. Thank you for understanding.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.width = "300px";
}

x.onmouseover = () => {
    x.style.width = "300px";
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.querySelectorAll(".card")` will return a collection of `.card` elements, so

```
x.onmouseover = () => { ... };
```

won't work.

You have following options to do what you want.

- Add `mouseover` event on all `.card` elements by looping over the collection returned by `.querySelectorAll()`

  ```js
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

  cards.forEach(card => {
    card.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
      if (event.target.matches('.card')) {
        event.target.style.width = '150px';
      }
    });
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .card {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  ```
- Add `mouseover` event on the common parent element of all `.card` elements and using `Event.target` property, increase the width of the `.card` element which triggered the `mouseover` event

  ```js
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');

  container.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('.card')) {
      event.target.style.width = '150px';
    }
  });
  ```

  ```css
  .card {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  ```
- Do this via CSS using `:hover` pseudo-class.

  ```css
  .card {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
  }

  .card:hover {
    width: 120px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  ```

**P.S:** Unlike `:hover`, when any `.card` element's width is increased on `mouseover` event, it doesn't resets back to original width when mouse pointer moves out of that `.card` element. If you need to do that and you don't want to use `:hover` pseudo-class, you will need to add `mouseout` event as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it slightly so that `x.onmouseover` is inside the loop, eg:

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.width = "300px";
  x[i].onmouseover = () => {
    //YOUR CODE HERE
  };
}
```

The alternative uses a technique called *bubbling*, where events 'bubble' up to parent elements from below. Using that, you get this:

```
document.body.onmouseover = (e)=>{
  if (e.target.classList.contains("card")) { //Check if event originator was a .card element
    //YOUR CODE HERE
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the elements inside the loop and define event listener on all of them:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.width = "300px";
  x[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
      this.style.width = "350px";
  })    
}
```

```css
.card{
height:20px;
 border:1px solid #ff8800;
 margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event name is `mouseover` and `mouseout` in javascript.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
x.forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    item.style.width = "400px";
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    item.style.width = "200px";
  });
})
```

```css
.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 0.2s; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

for(const el of x){
   el.onmouseover;
}

onmouseover = (el) => {
    el.target.style.width = "300px";
};
```

```css
.card{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="1">MyCard </div>
<div class="card"id="2">MyCard </div>
```